# Apply SAS Permissions on Azure Blob Storage Container in Python

Tags: python, azure, permissions

I'm trying to find out how to create a container obect that has SAS permission applied on it without supplying the account or account key.  I've done this in C# but looking to do this in Python.

```
sasToken = "https://samplestoragehotblob.blob.core.windows.net/samplecontainer?sv=2016-05-31&sr=c&sig=dfdLKJ.....kljsdflkjljsd=3027-09-11T17%3A16%3A57Z&sp=racwdl";
CloudBlobContainer cbContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(sasToken));
```

I can then work in the container with all the necessary permissions without specifying an account and key.  Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to not use the account key.  This was an acceptable compromise.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

def AccessTest():
    accountName = "Account Name"
    containerName = "Container Name"
    sasToken = "sv=2016-05-31&sr=c&sig=BhhYbf3............................-10-02T15%3A28%3A59Z&sp=racwdl"

    blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name = accountName, account_key = None, sas_token = sasToken)

    for blob in blobService.list_blobs(containerName):
        print blob.__getattribute__('name')
```

Answer (score -1):

Just as Summary, If you haven't generated SAS token,you can't avoid using account key.

You could follow the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#sas-examples) and use `generate_shared_access_signature`,`generate_container_shared_access_signature`,`generate_blob_shared_access_signature` to generate `SAS Token` for `azure storage account`,`container`,`blob` in python.

If you already generated `SAS token`, you could operate your container with `SAS token` instead of account key.

***Code Snippet:***

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.storage.blob import (
    BlockBlobService,
    ContainerPermissions,
)

accountName = "***"
accountKey = "***"
containerName = "***"

def GenerateSasToken():
    blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name=accountName, account_key=accountKey)
    sas_url = blobService.generate_container_shared_access_signature(containerName,ContainerPermissions.READ, datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
    # print sas_url
    return 'https://' + accountName + '.blob.core.windows.net/' + containerName + '?' + sas_url

def AccessTest(sastoken):
    blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name = accountName, account_key = None, sas_token = sastoken)
    BlockBlobService

    for blob in blobService.list_blobs(containerName):
        print blob.__getattribute__('name')

sastoken = GenerateSasToken()
print sastoken

AccessTest(sastoken)
```

In addition, you could try to use `Azure Key Vault`.

> The Azure Storage Account (ASA) key feature manages secret rotation
>   for you. It also removes the need for your direct contact with an ASA
>   key by offering Shared Access Signatures (SAS) as a method.

which mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-ovw-storage-keys).

Please refer to the [Azure Key Vault official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/) and it support [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/storage-account-key-operations).

Comment: You should have given example on how to upload a file using python azure SDK with only SAS token. Provided that sas key is generated already. This is what the OP asked. Your code merely mentions on how to generate SAS key which is irrelevant here.